# Intersect five different points of same layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, iteration

In ArcGis Desktop I have the following problem: I have a layer of sites, let them be hotels, for instance, and I want to find each place, where there are less than five hotels within a radius of 30 km.

I thought this might somehow work with iterating over the intersect function in the Modalbuilder. However, I have never used the iteration tool and am not quite sure, whether I'm doing this right. Additionally, how do I make sure, that it doesn't intersect with the same point twice, when I iterate over it?

[image]

Is there a different approach that would be better for this?

Comment: Convert points to grid and run focal statistics on it with that radius.

Comment: So are you saying once a hotel point has been found that it should be removed from the set of hotels so that it is not counted for another hotel? If this is the case why\how does one hotel have priority over another? May be edit your question, remove your duff model and show the data and what your expected out comes are?